# How to run appengine dev server programmatic(in java)?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

Recently, I want to create appengine tasks like "start dev server", "upload my webapp" in xsbt. I found the appengine plugin for xsbt(sbt-appengine), but I didn't understand how it works. I just got some keywords like "com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain", "-javaagent", "-Xbootclasspath". Anyone knows how to run local appengine development server programmatic? Or any document which describes full options?

Answer (score 2):

to run a local app engine server you would need run the "{appengine_SDK_directory}/bin/dev_appserver.extension {dir_to_your_project_war}".

the "extension" depends on yours operating system. It may be: cmd (win) or sh (linux).